# Email notification when using system monitoring

Tags: grails

I am doing a Grails project. And here are some requirements about the system monitoring as below:
1. Email notify team when system goes down
2. Email notify team system log daily
3. Email notify team when app is deployed

So I don't know what to meet my requirements. 
Could someone help me？

Answer (score 1):

1. Use any monitoring software or service. I use New Relic, but there are plenty to choose from. If you only need ping, use a ping monitoring service. I use a free Google script I found on the Internet, but it has had some false alerts.
2. Use the Quartz plugin to send the log at a daily basis, or a cron job or similar.
3. Maybe use a shell script that does the employment and sends an email as well, or it might exist a Grails event for deployment.